# The Complexity of Optimising over n variables

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

If I use one of the methods in `scipy.optimise` to find the global minimum of a function in $n$ variables.  How does the complexity of the problem then scale if I try to optimise over $n+1$, $n+2$ variables?

When I've looked online at resources [like this](http://links.uwaterloo.ca/math227docs/set4.pdf)
here isn't much explanation.

EDIT: So if I used a BFGS on a function that had 4 variables, and then 6 variables, would this be the same increase in 'difficulty' and time taken to get find global minimum as then going from 6 to 8 ? Does it depend more on the function itself, or is there an intrinsic law to these things ? Is this true if instead COBYLA was used ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very difficult to be precise about this because it will depend on many things. It will depend on, at least:

What method you are using, and for some methods whether you provide the jacobian or let the method approximate it;
the nature of the problem you are solving;
how far your initial guess is from the result.

Most (all?) of the methods will come down to solving a dim x dim system of linear equations, and so will scale at least like dim cubed. Typically linear equations A*x=b are solved by factorising A (for example into a product of matrices for which the euations are easy to solve, say triangular and permutation matrices). The factorisation is typically a dim cubed process.

However most (all?) may take many such steps, and it is possible that the number of steps could scale like dim, especially if your initial estimate is far from the result.

Comment: Thanks ! I think the thing I don;t understand is what you mean by solving the dim X dim system of equations. Wouldn't this mean the difficulty scales by dim^2 ?